# How to redirect user to new page after signing in with email, facebook, or google using firebaseui?

Tags: ionic-framework, authentication, facebook-login, firebaseui, google-signin

I am using the Iconic 4 framework and I'm trying to use the FirebaseUIAuth feature within my application but I am facing an issue when the user signs in.

Issue: When the user logs in, the sign in buttons disappear for the web & ios rendering of the application on my localhost (this is good), but I am having issues with the Android rendering. After logging in, the login/sign in buttons remain visible in the android rendering (not good...womp womp).

I have tried changing the signInFlow parameter to 'redirect' but the extent of my knowledge with the Ionic Framework has me a bit stumped since I am confused on how to get the login buttons redirect the user to a new view.

[app.module.ts file with firebaseUI config only]

```
const firebaseUiAuthConfig: firebaseui.auth.Config = {
  signInFlow: 'popup', /*tried using 'redirect' to fix android rendering*/
  signInOptions: [
    firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    {
      scopes: [
        'public_profile',
        'email',
        'user_likes',
        'user_friends'
      ],
      customParameters: {
        'auth_type': 'reauthenticate'
      },
      provider: firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
    },
    {
      requireDisplayName: true,
      provider: firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
    }
  ],
  tosUrl: '/terms',
  privacyPolicyUrl: '/privacy',
  credentialHelper: firebaseui.auth.CredentialHelper.NONE
};
```

[home.page.html file with firebaseui tag]

```
<ion-content padding>
  <firebase-ui></firebase-ui>

  <h1 *ngIf="afAuth.auth.currentUser">Welcome {{afAuth.auth.currentUser.displayName}}!</h1>

  <ion-button *ngIf="afAuth.auth.currentUser" (click)="signOut();">Sign Out</ion-button>
</ion-content>
```

[home.page.ts file with signout method]

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth,) {
  }

  signOut() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut().then(() => {
    location.reload();
    });
  }

}
```

I expected that the android rendering will only display:

Welcome some user!

But it also displays the sign in buttons that are configured with the firebaseui (google, facebook, email)

Comment: where is the condition of hiding button in your code??

Comment: I'm trying to hide <firebase-ui></firebase-ui> after login. It works on the rendering of iOS and the browser, but not on the rendering of Android. Would the hide condition be coded out in this tag like this:                                                                                        <firebase-ui *ngIf="hide"></firebase-ui>? From the brief research that i've done that is how buttons are hidden. Again, i'm new at this framework so just trying to learn as i go. Thanks for your help and guidance!

Comment: did you try using <firebase-ui *ngIf="hide"></firebase-ui> i think it should work

Comment: the compiler is showing an error saying "the declaration is undefined"